# Vue pass data into array specific item name

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs2

Hey I am really new to Vue and for this project I was trying to add data inside array using `.push()` . When I push data inside `totalPlayers` its suppose to get data as `totalPlayers[{data:[0,1,2,3]}]` but it currently saves data as `totalPlayers[{data: [] }, 0, 1, 2, 3]`. Is there a way to fix this? Here is my code below

JsFiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/xv2homt8/24/

**Method**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    totalPlayers:[{
     data:[],
    }],
    playerList:4,
  },
  methods: {
    buttonClicked(){
        for (var i = 0; i < this.playerList; i++) {
        console.log('i was '+i);
        this.totalPlayers.push(i);
        console.log(this.totalPlayers);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**View**

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="buttonClicked()">
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is array in first element of `totalPlayers` array, so try `totalPlayers[0].data.push`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    totalPlayers:[{
     data:[],
    }],
    playerList:4,
  },
  methods: {
    buttonClicked(){
        for (var i = 0; i < this.playerList; i++) {
        console.log('i was '+i);
        this.totalPlayers[0].data.push(i);
        console.log(this.totalPlayers);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="buttonClicked()">
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use this to push: `this.totalPlayers[0].data.push(i);`
since `totalPlayers` is an array and you want to add to it's first element that is an object
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0mn8fah/)